# Changing soundtrack in a movie clip

Tags: multimedia

What is the easiest way to change soundtrack of a movie clip? We recorded a clip using our camera, but the sound is not very interesting, hence we would like to use some music instead (we have an mp3 file). How can we swap the original sound in the clip for the one from mp3?

Comment: You have a huge selection of video editing software available for this. They range from simple to complicated. Depending on your system, you could check your repositories for some software.

Comment: @MaxMackie, I am looking for a really easy way. I am a bit worried that if I just start looking at a random software, it will be one of the more complicated ones, with gzillion options, etc.

Comment: Do you mean something akin to Windows Movie Maker? Or even more simple?

Comment: @MaxMackie, it could be even a command line tool, but I would appreciate an example in which I just need to substitute file names :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace the audio track of a video file using `mencoder`.

```
mencoder input.avi -o output.avi -ovc copy -oac copy -audiofile track.mp3
```

Warning: untested command.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/), which is a nice gui. It can do lots of other things, but I managed to figure out in a few minutes how to do this particular thing.